# PHP Regex to add a span tag

Tags: php, regex

I have these strings:

```
$string1 = 'api/1/get/friends/:id/connections';
$string2 = 'api/1/get/search/:name';
```

I need to add span tags between the slashes if-and-only-if the character "**:**" is found next to a slash.

```
$string1 = 'api/1/get/friends/<span>:id</span>/connections';
$string2 = 'api/1/get/search/<span>:name</span>';
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: What kind of weird API-url are you making?

Comment: @OptimusCrime My guess is that those are variables in a routing system...

Comment: @PeeHaa埽: Me too. But I still don't see the point of adding spans. Perhaps for documentation?

Comment: actually it is for an api docs page. i need to paint the variable in another color. @Casimir's solution worked just fine.

Comment: @OptimusChrime this is just for the api docs. It's a rest api based on Slim, but there was no automatic documentation generator (at least i haven't found one), so im trying to document it for the frontend programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This do the job:

```
$result = preg_replace ('~/\K:\w++~', '<span>$0</span>', $string);
```